# Equivalence of Lebesgue and Henstock-Kurzweil (Gauge) integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, gauge-integral

1. If $f$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable $\Longrightarrow$  $f$ is measurable.
2. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable $\Longleftrightarrow$ $|f|$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.
3. $|f|$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.

Can we use the above three relations to show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable  $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable, that is, can we drop the condition $f\ge 0$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468045/equivalence-of-the-lebesgue-integral-and-the-henstock-kurzweil-integral-on-nonne) ?

In a nutshell does there exits functions that are not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable but are Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: In your points 2 and 3, are you assuming that $f$ is measurable? They are false otherwise.

Comment: @ArnaudD. What do you mean? If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f$ is obviously measurable and if $f$ is HK integrable, then it is measurable from 1.

Comment: But $|f|$ can be HK integrable without $f$ being so (if you accept the axiom of choice).

Comment: @ArnaudD.So, 3 does not hold? I know integrability of $f$ $\not \Rightarrow$ integrability of $|f|$, but the converse holds , right ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. $|f|$ can be integrable even without $f$ being measurable.

Comment: @ArnaudD.No I am not asking about that. I am saying 3 holds without any mention of $f$ being measurable or not. If $|f|$ is HK integrable then $f$ is HK integrable ?.

Comment: If 3 was true, combining it with 1 would contradict my previous comment. For an explicit counterexample : consider a non-measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ and the function that maps $x$ to $1$ if $x\in A$ and $-1$ otherwise.